# WSO2 API Manager Swagger Integration (Model schema)

Tags: wso2, swagger

I have some questions regarding WSO2 API manager swagger integration.

1) I want to add a model schema to the swagger API, for this, I have edited swagger doc and added model to it. But it is not showing the model schema in swagger console.

2) Can i upgrade swagger to a latest version ??

3) Where the swagger json files will be saved when we create an API in API manager ??

Answer (score 1):

I comment your questions:

1) I have the same issue :-( Did you find the solution at last?

2) AFAIK, you can't update a single component of a WSO2 product. It's a combo. APIMgr uses swagger 1.1 version. I think is too old and must be updateable, but..

3) You can find this .json files entering by http:// apimanagerserver:9443[+offset]/carbon -> Resources -> Browse and navigate to: /_system/governance/apimgt/applicationdata/api-docs/YourAPIName-1.0-admin/api-doc.json